# Python 3.5.2 - cx_freeze unable import tkinter *

Tags: python, python-3.5, importerror, cx-freeze

i have been searching two days for solution for my problem. I try to build my .py script and it works fine without any errors. Unfortunately my .exe file shows this message:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LKiZ.png)
I made a simple program as a test and it made the same thing.

This is the program:

```
from tkinter import *

def do():
    global top
    top = Toplevel(root)
    button=Button(top, text = "Click", command = pis).pack()
def pis():
    global top
    label = Label(top, text="You clicked").pack()
root = Tk()


button=Button(root, text = "Click", command = do).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and this is the setup:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("prog.py", base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SeaofBTC-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":[]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Sea of BTC trading application",
    executables = executables
    )
```

I think the problem may be with "from tkinter import *" because everything build without any issue.
Also, I tried to find missing .dll with Dependency Walker and this is the result: [Dependency Walker IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqKDw.png)

If anyone can help, i would really appreciate it.